# Query to get data from four tables

Tags: mysql

i have following scheme,
**purchase_order**

```
+-------------------+----------------------+
| purchase_order_id | purchase_order       |
+-------------------+----------------------+
|                54 | Purchase Order 12345 |
|                56 | po-laptop-hp-3       |
|                57 | po-laptop-hp-1       |
+-------------------+----------------------+
```

**purchase_order_detail**

```
+--------------------------+-------------------+---------+------------------+
| purchase_order_detail_id | purchase_order_id | item_id | ordered_quantity |
+--------------------------+-------------------+---------+------------------+
|                       61 |                54 |     279 |              500 |
|                       62 |                54 |     286 |              700 |
|                       63 |                56 |     279 |               43 |
|                       64 |                57 |     279 |               43 |
|                       65 |                57 |     286 |               43 |
|                       66 |                57 |     287 |               43 |
+--------------------------+-------------------+---------+------------------+
```

**delivery_order**

```
+-------------------+--------------------------+-------------------+
| delivery_order_id | purchase_order_detail_id | recieved_quantity |
+-------------------+--------------------------+-------------------+
|                62 |                       61 |               250 |
|                63 |                       62 |               300 |
|                64 |                       63 |                34 |
|                65 |                       64 |                34 |
|                66 |                       65 |                34 |
|                67 |                       66 |                34 |
|                68 |                       61 |                34 |
|                69 |                       61 |                34 |
+-------------------+--------------------------+-------------------+
```

**stock**

```
+----------+-------------------+------------+----------+------------------+---------------+
| stock_id | delivery_order_id | project_id | quantity | initial_quantity | stock_type_id |
+----------+-------------------+------------+----------+------------------+---------------+
|       12 |                62 |          1 |       60 |               60 |             1 |
|       13 |                63 |          1 |      120 |              120 |             1 |
|       14 |                63 |          1 |       50 |               50 |             1 |
|       15 |                64 |          1 |       12 |               12 |             1 |
|       16 |                62 |          1 |      120 |              120 |             1 |
|       17 |                62 |          1 |       12 |               12 |             1 |
+----------+-------------------+------------+----------+------------------+---------------+
```

i have write this query but it returns duplicate results

```
      SELECT po.created_on
           , po.purchase_order
           , i.item_name
           , u.unit_name
           , pod.ordered_quantity
           , do.recieved_quantity
           , do.recieved_on
           , po.remarks
        FROM purchase_order        po
           , purchase_order_detail pod
           , delivery_order        do
           , stock                 s
           , item                  i
           , unit                  u
       WHERE u.unit_id                    = i.unit_id 
         AND i.item_id                    = pod.item_id
         AND po.purchase_order_id         = pod.purchase_order_id
         AND pod.purchase_order_detail_id = do.purchase_order_detail_id  
         AND do.delivery_order_id         = s.delivery_order_id
         AND s.project_id                 = 1 
    ORDER BY po.purchase_order_id
           , pod.item_id
           ;
```

The results

```
+---------------------+----------------------+------------+-----------+------------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------------------------+
| created_on          | purchase_order       | item_name  | unit_name | ordered_quantity | recieved_quantity | recieved_on         | remarks                               |
+---------------------+----------------------+------------+-----------+------------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------------------------+
| 2015-02-24 22:48:15 | Purchase Order 12345 | HP Laptops | Unit      |              500 |               250 | 2015-02-21 00:00:00 | Adding first Purchase Order as a Test |
| 2015-02-24 22:48:15 | Purchase Order 12345 | HP Laptops | Unit      |              500 |               250 | 2015-02-21 00:00:00 | Adding first Purchase Order as a Test |
| 2015-02-24 22:48:15 | Purchase Order 12345 | Lenovo     | Unit      |              700 |               300 | 2015-02-21 00:00:00 | Adding first Purchase Order as a Test |
| 2015-02-24 22:48:15 | Purchase Order 12345 | Lenovo     | Unit      |              700 |               300 | 2015-02-21 00:00:00 | Adding first Purchase Order as a Test |
| 2015-02-24 22:55:40 | po-laptop-hp-3       | HP Laptops | Unit      |               43 |                34 | 2015-02-21 00:00:00 | dfgsdfgsd                             |
+---------------------+----------------------+------------+-----------+------------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------------------------+
```

relationship is one to many from top to bottom.
What I wanted to get is the each purchase_order , his ordered quantity of each item, and total recieved quantity, and quantity in stock where project_id = 1 from stock.

i am expecting something like this,

```
+-------------------+---------+------------------+---------------+----------+
| purchase_order_id | item_id | ordered_quantity | totalReceived | quantity |
+-------------------+---------+------------------+---------------+----------+
|                54 |     279 |              500 |           314 |      192 |
|                54 |     286 |              700 |           300 |      170 |
|                56 |     279 |               43 |            34 |       12 |
+-------------------+---------+------------------+---------------+----------+
```

Comment: What are your expected results form the sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Thank you for clearing up the mistake in my first part. I realize now that we cannot do all calculations in a single query (because we group on different columns in various parts) so I started by writing individual subqueries and joining them together. The steps went something like this:

- Get the sum of received total received quantity for each 
  *purchase_order_detail_id* from the delivery_order table.
- Join that subquery with the delivery_order table itself to get the totalReceived for the various *delivery_order_id* values.
- Join that result set with the purchase_order_detail table to get the purchase_order_id, item_id, and ordered_quantity for each *delivery_order_id*.

We now have a result set including the delivery_order_id, purchase_order_id, item_id, ordered_quantity, and total received. The last two things are:

- Get the SUM() of quantity for each delivery_order_id from the stock table.
- Join that with our above result set on the condition that order_id matches (so we will only get one row) and that project_id is 1 (so we only get the necessary delivery_order_id values). I put that condition in the `WHERE` clause of the sum subquery.

Here is your final query:

```
SELECT tmp1.purchase_order_id, tmp1.item_id, tmp1.ordered_quantity, tmp1.totalReceived, tmp2.quantity
FROM(
  SELECT tmp.delivery_order_id, pod.purchase_order_id, pod.item_id, pod.ordered_quantity, tmp.totalReceived
  FROM purchase_order_detail pod
  JOIN(
    SELECT do.delivery_order_id, tmp.purchase_order_detail_id, tmp.totalReceived
    FROM delivery_order do
    JOIN(
      SELECT do.purchase_order_detail_id, SUM(do.received_quantity) AS totalReceived
      FROM delivery_order do
      GROUP BY do.purchase_order_detail_id) tmp ON tmp.purchase_order_detail_id = do.purchase_order_detail_id) 
    tmp ON tmp.purchase_order_detail_id = pod.purchase_order_detail_id) tmp1
JOIN(
  SELECT s.delivery_order_id, SUM(quantity) AS quantity
  FROM stock s
  WHERE s.project_id = 1
  GROUP BY s.delivery_order_id) tmp2 ON tmp2.delivery_order_id = tmp1.delivery_order_id;
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fed35/21). It shows all of the intermediate steps too, if you'd like to see how the results came together individually.

Comment: you query is quite close but it returns rowing result, running this said that look at the difference of ordered and recievedquantity.

Comment: Hmm, I will try to work it out. Can you edit your question with the correct results I should get?

Comment: the problem with your query is when their is many received_quantity against one ordered_quantity, then it returns incorrect result, else correct. and the same happened with my query.

Comment: @MTaqi I'm sorry for the misunderstanding. I have reworked this out and replaced my answer with a working solution.

Comment: @MTaqi have you had any opportunity to test the edited solution? Any problems?

Comment: Actually, you query is not working giving out errors.

Comment: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'temp1.ordered_quantity' in 'field list'

Comment: @MTaqi simple typo. Should have been tmp1. Without the 'E'

Comment: @Strawberry fiddle seems to be down right now but I believe so. I test every fiddle before I actually add it in my question. I remember correcting the typo in there, simply forgot to edit question.

Comment: I test it on my db also

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your query to use DISTINCT and OUTER JOINs instead of cartesian ("comma") joins.

```
  SELECT DISTINCT po.created_on
       , po.purchase_order
       , i.item_name
       , u.unit_name
       , pod.ordered_quantity
       , do.recieved_quantity
       , do.recieved_on
       , po.remarks
    FROM purchase_order po
    LEFT JOIN purchase_order_detail pod USING (purchase_order_id)
    LEFT JOIN delivery_order do USING (purchase_order_detail_id)
    LEFT JOIN stock s USING (delivery_order_id)
    LEFT JOIN item i USING (item_id)
    LEFT JOIN unit u USING (unit_id)
ORDER BY po.purchase_order_id
       , pod.item_id
       ;
```